# how to retrieve excel according to user

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am using HtML5 and javascript. I want to  know that how to read an excel file from the user - I have some code to read the file from the defined path:

Html

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="checkfile(this);" />
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="readdata(1, 2)" value="Submit" />
```

Javascript

```
function checkfile(sender) {
    var validExts = new Array(".xlsx", ".xls", ".csv");
    var fileExt = sender.value;
    fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
        alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
           validExts.toString() + " types.");
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

function readdata(x,y) {
    try {
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        excel.Visible = false;
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test.xls");// alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
        var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
        var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
        //alert(data);
        drawWithexcelValue(data);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
    //    return data;
}
```

checkfile is for the validation,and readdata is to read the file.
So now I want to read the Excel file from the unknown path from the disk.

**1)** I have to modify in such a way that  the function contains two arguments and when I click on the submit button it will read the file and perform the action.

**2)** How would I know whether the chosen file is being read or not for the case when it does not show the output?

If anyone wants more information regarding this, feel is free to ask!

Comment: `So now i want to read the Excel file from the unknown path from the disk ..` > What do you mean ? You want to let the user choose a file on his drive ? Then you may be interrested in the File API, which its use is well explained [in this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: i have read this already ..but because of i am new to this thing ,i am unable to modify that code according to my code ,i,e. its function shuld contain 2 argument, and on clicking the submit button contain onclick event

Comment: i have edited my comment please refer to that, this will be really helpful for me if you help me ...

Comment: You should first try yourself and come back here with your failing code (and the eventual errors you get). That's how SO works. From where I see it you have a good documentation to start.

Comment: i have tried this already but i am failing to do so

Comment: If you already tried and failed, that means you already have what SO requests. Just start a new post (or update this one), post the code that is not working (as I understood the code here above is a functional one), explain what you're trying to do (ie : read a user-specified excel file) and what exactly is the problem with the code you post, and you may find people able to help you.